# Asynchronous function not producing immediate result inside while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I am new to nodejs and what I have done is I have connected LCD Panel and 4x4 Membrane matrix keypad to Raspberry Pi and I have programmed them using Node.js. What I want to achieve is whenever a key is pressed it should be displayed immediately on the LCD panel and when I press # it should stop taking input.

For this I have used packages LCD https://www.npmjs.com/package/lcd and RPIO https://github.com/jperkin/node-rpio and since I have to continuously check for user input I have put the code for taking input in while loop & inside that I have written the print statement and that is where the problem is coming. LCD panel doesn't display any character when I press a key on keypad but when I press #, the program exits and all the characters are displayed on the LCD panel.

The code that I have written is as follows.

```
var rpio = require('rpio');
var Lcd = require('lcd'),//This is asynchronous function
    lcd = new Lcd({
        rs: 18,
        e: 23,
        data: [24, 17, 27, 22],
        cols: 8,
        rows: 2
    });
var matrix=[[1,2,3,'A'],
            [4,5,6,'B'],
            [7,8,9,'C'],
            ['*',0,'#','D']]
var row=[37,35,33,31];
var col=[29,23,40,38];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    rpio.open(col[i], rpio.OUTPUT, rpio.HIGH);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    rpio.open(row[i], rpio.INPUT, rpio.PULL_UP);
}
var code="";
var comeout=0;
lcd.on('ready', function() {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    //start of keypad code
    while(true){
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            rpio.write(col[j],rpio.LOW);
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if(rpio.read(row[i])==0){
                    console.log(matrix[i][j]);
                    lcd.print(matrix[i][j]);
                    if(matrix[i][j]=='#'){
                        comeout=1;
                        break;
                    }
                    while(rpio.read(row[i])==0);
                }
            }
            if(comeout==1)
                break;
            else
                rpio.write(col[j],rpio.HIGH);
        }
        if(comeout==1)
            break;
    }
    //end of keypad code
});

// If ctrl+c is hit, free resources and exit.
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.close();
    process.exit();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to break your code to small pieces and focus on the problem.

Comment: you cannot use `while(true)` loops that way in JS. That's why you have events to get noticed about keypresses for exmple. Check out `rpio.poll()`. Since I don't fully understand how your two for loops work and the `rpio.write()` and `rpio.read()` you utilize there, I'm not able to rewrite your code

Comment: I'm guessing that `col` and `row` contain some kind of bit-masks!?

Comment: You use Pin 23 for both LCD enable and `col[1]`; perhaps that's the problem. There is nothing wrong with you usage of `while(true)` because you scan over your key matrix (rows and cols) without using any interupts or other event sources.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, yes it is. It's like using `while(true)` in JS to check for changing (keyboard/mouse-)button state. It's basically an infinite loop, that never interrupts to enable any other JS-code to execute; like the code behind `lcd.print()`, wich seems to stack up. Until this loop is terminated (by pressing `#`). Then the stack is flushed and all the (pending) async code is executed. And that's exactly the problem he describes.

Comment: @Thomas  I looked into the code of the LCD module https://github.com/fivdi/lcd/blob/master/lcd.js. The developers of LCD enqueue async operations for each print call. Operations in this queue will be called all in sequence with the next "tick" of the event loop. I can not understand why they do that, printing on the LCD is fast enough to handle it synchronous. Now I must agree with you. ;-) But Vikas also used PIO 23 of Raspi for both the enable pin of the LCD and one of the column input pins of the key matrix.  I wonder how he connected the same PIO to two pins?

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion with @Thomas above, I would suggest you simulate the `while(true)` loop with `setImediate` calls in which you request the matrix and perform the LCD.print. This is because the LCD.print adds operations to javascripts event queue. But the operations of the event queue are blocked until the actual operation is completed. It would never complete as long as you are in the `while(true)` loop.

So you must end the active operation and give the event loop control, which in turn executes the print commands. But at the same time you must assure that you scan the key matrix again as long as you do not press the "#" key.

Here is an example:

```
lcd.on('ready', function() 
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  setImediate(
  function scanMatrix()
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
    {
      rpio.write(col[j],rpio.LOW);
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
      {
        if(rpio.read(row[i])==0)
        {
          console.log(matrix[i][j]);
          lcd.print(matrix[i][j]);
          if(matrix[i][j]!='#')
          {
            setImmediate(scanMatrix);
          }
          while(rpio.read(row[i])==0);
        }
      }
      rpio.write(col[j],rpio.HIGH);
    }
  });
});
```

The code is not tested because I have no raspi here. It should give you an Idea of how to solve the problem.

A really cool ;-) solution would be to add a microcontroller (MSP430, ...) to the key matrix. The MC scans the matrix and transfers keypresses to the raspi via SPI or I2C. .... OK, ok, ok don't beat me ;-)